# Is there a way for me turn json data into positional arguments and their respective values in python?

Tags: python, json, keyword-argument

I am new to python and have been fascinated with **kwargs. So my question is, suppose I have a json of this format:

```
{
  "arguments" : 
              { 
                "argument1" : "value1",  
                "argument2" : "value2", 
                "argument3": "value3"
              }
 }
```

How would I be able to pass into a function requires for keyword arguments with the help of **kwarg.

```
def function1(**kwargs):
    beer=foo.bar(**kwargs)
```

Where `foo.bar` only takes in keyword arguments, i.e.

```
beer=foo.bar(argument1=value1, argument2=value2,....)
```

Comment: If your dict is called `d`, you'd call `function1(**d["arguments"])`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. Is there a resource which will teach me more about python from this pov?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_args = {
    'a': 'hi',
    'b': 'hello',
    'c': 'hey'
}


def my_func(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Pass my_args in as keyword arguments:

```
my_func(**my_args)
```

Pass my_args in as positional arguments:

```
my_func(*my_args.values())
```